# Do I have to add alternative ad network's SDK into project of app?

Tags: ios, sdk, admob, ads

I'm using interstitial ads of admob to my ios game. I want to use alternative ad network because of high request but low impression. My question is do I have to add alternative ad network's SDK into my project? If I just use admob mediation without adding alternative network's SDK into my xcode project to adding new ad network source, Is it enough?

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close as a question not about programming.  Maybe you could edit so that there's no doubt?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be **have** to add alternative Ad Networks SDKs that will be used by the AdMob SDK using an appropriate **adapter** as written in Admob's documentation:

> 2. Add network adapters and SDKs
>
> You're now ready to download and add to your project the adapters and
>   SDKs of all the ad networks you'd like to serve ads from. You can find
>   links to them on the mediation networks page.
>
> To add the downloaded network adapters/SDKs in Xcode, right click on
>   your project and click Add Files to project.
>
> Note: You may consider integrating adapters and SDKs from networks
>   that you're not currently using but might use in the future. If you do
>   this, you'll be able to start serving ads from these networks simply
>   by making a configuration change on the AdMob front-end, without
>   requiring a code change to your app. Weigh this against the increase
>   in app binary size that each additional SDK will add.
>   3. Include network configurations
>
> You need to include any frameworks, compiler flags, or linker flags
>   that your chosen networks require. For your convenience, the mediation
>   networks page has links to each network's instructions.
>
> There is no need to write additional code to create ad views from each
>   ad network. Mediation invokes each ad network's adapter and SDK as
>   necessary to create ads. Further below you'll see how to set up
>   mediation listeners that notify you of ad events for all of your
>   networks.

quoted from this link (where you can find additional instructions too): https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/mediation#adding_mediation_to_your_project